# setupController executing even after this.transitionTo in afterModel

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

The below is the afterModel code.

```
if (needNotTransition)
{
        console.log("Transforming in the after model");
        this.transitionTo("setup.route2")
        return;
}
```

Though I execute transitionTo, it is executing the setupController function. Is this behavior expected ? It is very odd!

Comment: You'll need to add more context than this, where is this, what's needNotTransition etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to abort the transition explicitly in `afterModel` hook:

```
afterModel: function(model, transition) {
    if (/*condition*/) {
        transition.abort();

        this.transitionTo('other.route');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. But is it expected to go to setupController after the transitionTo in afterModel ?

Comment: I'am not sure about that. I prefer to be as straight as possible in the code; something like `this.tranisitonTo` in a scope of some hook isn't so direct way to tell 'not to call other hook'. In other hand, it seems strange to call a function (`setupController`), the result of which we do not need. I think it's more a bug than a feature.